# How to autofill value on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have the following example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w1VR9Spk8y58b_f8cHktOUIc6uJVRnLjG0GR_43N62M/edit?usp=sharing).

I have a random value that is no spaced exactly, (some have 10 empty between them other 30). I would like to have some value equally added in the empty spaces.

I do not care If I have to repeat the operation 40 times because the values are not spaced correctly, but I can't find a good function that does what I would like to do.

Comment: could those number in between be random or you want them to be sequential?

Comment: sequential like the exemple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- go to **File**
- select **Spreadsheet settings...**
- select **Calculation**
- turn on **Iterative calculation**
- hit **<kbd>Save settings</kbd>** button

[image: 9]

- paste this formula into **A3**, **A19**, **A34**, **A60**, **A79**, **A101** etc.

```
=IF(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1)=INDEX(FILTER(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A");N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")));1;1);
ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1)&";";COUNTA(ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("A"&
ROW()-1)+(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"&INDEX(FILTER(IF(N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));ROW(INDIRECT("A"&
ROW()&":A")););IF(N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));));1;1)-1))-2))));";"));
"##"));ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1)+(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"&INDEX(FILTER(IF(N(
INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")););IF(N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));ROW(
INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));));1;1)-1))-2)* (INDEX(FILTER(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A");N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW(
)&":A")));1;1)-INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1))/(ROWS(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"&INDEX(FILTER(IF(N(INDIRECT("A"&
ROW()&":A"));ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));); IF(N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&
":A"));));1;1)-1)))* (ABS(MINUS(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1);INDEX(FILTER(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A");N(
INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")));1;1)))-(ABS(MINUS(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1);INDEX(FILTER(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&
":A");N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")));1;1)))* (100/(((COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"&INDEX(FILTER(IF(
N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")););IF(N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));ROW(
INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"));));1;1));"<>""")+1)-1)* 100))))/ABS(MINUS(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1);INDEX(
FILTER(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A");N(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")));1;1)));"##")))
```

[image: 9]

- if there is a need to add decimals for ultimate accuracy, then edit **`"##"`** into **`"##.###"`**
- auto-filled cells are in `TEXT()` format so if you want to work with **A** column you will need to convert it into numbers with `VALUE()` - for example something like **`=ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE({A7;A8;A9}))`**